# Search on google app engine

Tags: gae-search, google-app-engine-python

I am using google app engine search api for searching.I want to merge the results of multiple queries into one.How do I do that in python.

Comment: Queries against different indexes?

Comment: No using the same index.Since google provides only full text  search,I am trying to build a function for partial search.The results contain information like facets also.I want to use them as well.But if i merge them into a list,i am unable to get facet information.How do i go about it.Eagerly waiting for a response.